Doctrine Migrations: Repeatedly Generating the Same ALTER TABLE Statement
I recently upgraded my Symfony project from 5.4 to 6.4.13. Now, I am encountering an issue with Doctrine Migrations in my Symfony project. When I run the doctrine:migrations:diff command, it generates an ALTER TABLE statement to change a column type and default value. However, after applying the migration and running the doctrine:migrations:diff command again, the same ALTER TABLE statement is generated repeatedly.
Here is the generated SQL statement:
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE my_entity CHANGE my_column my_column DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT 0');

Entity:
#[ORM\Entity]
class MyEntity
{
    ...

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'float', nullable: true, options: ['default' => 0])]
    #[Assert\Range(min: 0)]
    private ?float $myColumn = 0;

    ...
}

Migration Configuration:
doctrine.yaml:
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        mappings:
            App:
                type: attribute
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App

doctrine_migrations.yaml:
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        'App\Migrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'migration_versions'
            version_column_name: 'version'
            version_column_length: 192
            executed_at_column_name: 'executed_at'
    check_database_platform: true

Project Details:

Symfony version: 6.4.13
PHP version: 8.1
Composer dependencies include doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle v3.3.1 and doctrine/doctrine-bundle v2.13.1.

Question:
Why, in the first place, does Doctrine generate this ALTER TABLE statement, and why does Doctrine keep generating the same ALTER TABLE statement, after it has been executed?

The combination of nullable: true and options: ['default' => 0] can cause inconsistencies. A NULL value and a default value of 0 can be interpreted differently by the database schema.
Solution:
Adjust the myColumn definition to remove ambiguity, reapply the migration and see what happen
#[ORM\Column(type: 'float', nullable: false, options: ['default' => 0])]
private float $myColumn = 0;

